# Code editor for Java source and Qt Android

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator does not have built in editing capabilities for Java source code from Qt Android projects. At the moment I just edit the Java code in Notepad++ which is not very convenient (no code completion or warnings when import statements are missing). What is the best way for editing source code which uses Qt Android classes (for instance `org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity`)?

Regards,

Comment: Have you considered setting up a Java language server? https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-4.10/creator-language-servers.html

Comment: For now I have setup a fake Android Studio project (with dummy QtAndroid classes) and do all the code work there. I prefer this because it helps a lot with auto completing missing import statements.